# Is ADL the only way to call a friend inline function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, friend, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

Let us define `f`, as a friend function of `S`, inside the declaration of `S`:

```
struct S
{
    friend void f() {}
};
```

I cannot find a way to call `f`.

**Is it true, then, that such an inline friend function can only be called with [argument-dependant lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)?**

```
struct S
{
    friend void f() {}
    friend void g(S const&) {}
} const s;

int main()
{
    // f();     // error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
    // S::f();  // error: 'f' is not a member of 'S'
    g(s);
    // S::g(s); // error: 'g' is not a member of 'S'
}
```

Bonus: what if I want to get a function-pointer/`std::function`/lambda to `g`?

Comment: Note that if you declare (but not define) `f` before *or after* the definition of `S`, all is well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it true, then, that such an inline friend function can only be called with argument-dependant lookup?

Yes. As specified in [[namespace.memdef]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#3):

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template. the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup
>   ([basic.lookup.unqual]) or qualified lookup ([basic.lookup.qual]).

Since the *only* declaration of `f` is its inline definition, it's not made visible to qualified or unqualified lookup. ADL however, has a special provision for such friend functions, [[basic.lookup.argdep]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.argdep#4):

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as
>   the lookup performed when the associated namespace is used as a
>   qualifier ([namespace.qual]) except that:
>
> - Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates declared in associated classes are visible within their respective
>     namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup
>     ([class.friend]).

---

As for your bonus question, a lambda should do it:

```
auto exposed_g = [](S const& s){ g(s); };
```

It wraps the ADL into its body. Though the usual caveats about return type deduction apply. It will be a value (assuming you don't return `void`).

Comment: the _"**first** declares"_ intrigues me. Does it mean for `f` to be visible it must be declared _before_ it is define in `S`? If yes: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a10f693434919727

Comment: @YSC - It can also be declared afterwards. The meaning here that if it's the only declaration available up to a point, it isn't visible up to that point.

Answer (score 10):

The name `f` is declared in a [friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend), even it becomes the member of the [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) which contains `S`, but it's not visible for name lookup, unless it's redeclared at namespace scope. If not, it could be found only by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

> Names introduced by friend declarations within a non-local class `X` become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of `X`, but they do not become visible to ordinary name lookup (neither unqualified nor qualified) unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through ADL which considers both namespaces and classes.

Comment: _"unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided"_ would make me answer "No." to the question. (or at least, "It depends")

Comment: @MartinBonner - There once was a thing called "friend name injection". It was removed towards the first standard publication. Here's the paper, with rationale included http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0777.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No. You should just declare function properly.

```
struct S;
inline void f();
inline void g(S const&);

struct S
{
    friend void f() {}
    friend void g(S const&) {}
} const s;

int main()
{
    f(); // Ok
    // S::f();  // error: 'f' is not a member of 'S'
    g(s);
    // S::g(s); // error: 'g' is not a member of 'S'
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IkZxsjRVRsb0GupQ)